# powershell wildcard array in the where clause

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wildcard

I'm struggling with a PowerShell Where clause with an array that contains wildcards. Here's the command in my much larger code,

```
$excludedOUs = @("*OU=Loaners,*", "*OU=InStock,*", "*OU=Conference Room,*","*OU=Training,*") 
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $targetOU -Property LastLogonDate,LastLogon | 
          Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notin $excludedOUs } | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName, @{l='LastLogonDate';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
```

I want to return a list of machines from the $targetOU but I want to exclude a list of sub-OUs from the $targetOU. I've seen multiple posts that explain why this is failing (wildcards not allowed in "notin", need to use -like and -notlike with wilcards, etc.), and I've also seen the suggestions of using Regex to solve the problem. Unfortunately, my eyes always glaze over at the first sight of regular expressions and I can never figure out how to use them correctly. Ultimately, I'd like to not have to use the wildcards in the array at all. If the $excludedOUs array was,

```
$excludedOUs = @("Loaners", "InStock", "Conference Room", "Training")
```

I would prefer it. But, I need to use the wildcards because the sub-OU is only a part of the  DistinguishedName property. Additionally, the array may not always be limited to just these four items. It might be a single item, or none, or dozens. I won't know how others in the organization will use this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, `-in` and `-contains` and their negated variants only perform whole-value, literal *equality* comparisons.

Unfortunately, **neither `-like`, the [wildcard matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like), nor `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), support an *array* of patterns** to match against, as of PowerShell (Core) 7.4:

- Having this ability (with *any one* of the patterns matching being considered an overall match) would be useful; [GitHub issue #2132](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2132) asks for it to be implemented in a future [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) version.

The **workaround** is to **construct a *single* [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) that uses *alternation* (`|`)** that you can **use with `-match` / `-notmatch`**, which is easy to do programmatically:

- Construct your array with *literal substrings*, i.e. *without* `*` characters, given that `-match` / `-notmatch` performs *substring* matching by default.

  - Note: Conversely, this means that extra effort is needed to perform *whole-value* or *prefix* / *suffix* matching with a regex, namely by stipulating matching at the start (`^`) and/or end (`$`) of the input strings.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Join the array elements with `|` via [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) to form a *single string* that represents a regex with alternation, which means that *any one of the substrings* matches.

  - Note: If the literal substrings happen to contain regex metacharacters such as `.` or `+`, you must additionally *escape* them, using the [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) .NET method - see the relevant comment in the source code below.
    The alternative is to perform character-individual escaping with `\`, which is only an option in array *literals*.
- Use that string with `-notmatch`

```
# Define the exclusions as literal substrings, without "*"
$excludedOUs = 
  @("OU=Loaners,", "OU=InStock,", "OU=Conference Room,","OU=Training,")

# Join them with "|", to construct a single regex that matches
# any one of the substrings.
# In cases where the array elements contain regex metacharacters (see above), 
# use the following instead:
#   $regexExcludedOUs = $excludedOUs.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
$regexExcludedOUs = $excludedOUs -join '|'

# Use the regex with -notmatch
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $targetOU -Property LastLogonDate,LastLogon | 
  Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $regexExcludedOUs } |
  Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName, @{l='LastLogonDate';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
```

---

<sup>[1] Two examples that in essence use the same technique as in the rest of the answer:

*Whole-string* matching: `$regexes = 'fo+', 'ba[r]'; $combinedRegex = '^({0})$' -f ($regexes -join '|')`

`$combinedRegex` then contains `^(fo+|ba[r])$` verbatim.

*Prefix* matching: `$literalPrefixes = 'fo.', 'ba+'; $combinedRegex = '^({0})' -f ($literalPrefixes.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')`

`$combinedRegex` then contains `^(fo\.|ba\+)` verbatim.</sup>

Answer (score -3):

To achieve your goal of excluding specific sub-OUs from the result based on partial matches within the DistinguishedName, you can use the -notlike operator with wildcards in your Where-Object clause. You can modify your code like this:

$excludedOUs = @("Loaners", "InStock", "Conference Room", "Training")

## Create an array of regex patterns based on $excludedOUs

$excludedPatterns = $excludedOUs | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }

## Join the patterns with "|" for regex "or" matching

$regexPattern = ($excludedPatterns -join '|')

Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $targetOU -Property LastLogonDate, LastLogon |
Where-Object { $*.DistinguishedName -notmatch $regexPattern } |
Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName, @{l='LastLogonDate';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($*.LastLogon)}}

Explanation:

The $excludedPatterns array is created by escaping any special characters in each element of $excludedOUs using [regex]::Escape($_). This ensures that the strings are treated as literal strings in the regular expression.

The $regexPattern variable is created by joining the $excludedPatterns array using the | character, which acts as an "or" in regular expressions.

The Where-Object clause then uses the -notmatch operator with the $regexPattern to exclude entries where the DistinguishedName matches any of the excluded patterns.

This way, you can exclude specific sub-OUs from the result based on partial matches within the DistinguishedName without the need for wildcards in the array.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy